# Point of intersection between two circles how do I get the point?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Circle1  with $(1,1)$ and $r=1$

Circle2 with $(3,2.5)$ and $ r=2$

Best way to calculate the intersection without a calculator on a piece of paper, I tried many ways which I saw on the internet and spend much time, but my results are  mostly wrong.

I really don't know if it's because of the formulas or because my little errors, does someone know a good way? Which is not so complicated? A proper formula, maybe someone can show me how he calculated it?

Comment: One thing to consider is that the points of intersection (if they exist) are symmetric about the line connecting the two centers of the circles.  The circles intersect if and only if the distance between the centers is less than or equal to the sum of the radii.

Comment: yeah, actually they are intersecting but I need to get the point cor. where they meet. How go I get the 2 Points?

Comment: @hardmath : That "the circles intersect if and only if the distance between the centers is less than or equal to the sum of the radii" is not true if one of the circles is in the interior of the other, as in the present case. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @hardmath : And now the question has been altered.  However, your statement is still not true in cases where one circle is inside the other.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  Maybe I've miscalculated, but the distance between centers is $\frac{5}{2}$, and the two radii are $1$ and $2$ respectively.  So I don't see how one circle can be inside the other (since the center of each lies outside the other).  **Edit**: Okay, I see the edit history now.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see that you've changed the question since I posted this answer.  The answer below is correct for the question as initially stated.

The same technique will find the points of intersection to the later modified problem.

<s>If you just draw the picture you can see that they don't intersect.</s>

But one can also look at their two equations:
$$
(x-1)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 1^2 = 1 \tag 1
$$
$$
(x-1)^2 + (y-2.5)^2 = 2^2 = 4 \tag 2
$$
Subtracting the left side of $(1)$ from the left side of $(2)$ and likewise on the right sides, we get
$$
(y-2.5)^2 - (y-3)^2 = 4-1 = 3.
$$
Expanding the two squares, we get
$$
(y^2 - 5y + 6.25) - (y^2 - 6y + 9) = 3.
$$
Then:
$$
y - 2.75 = 3 \quad\text{so}\quad y = 5.75.
$$
Plugging $5.75$ in place of $y$ in $(1)$ we get
$$
(x-1)^2 + (5.75-3)^2 = 1
$$
or
$$
(x-1)^2 = 1 - 2.75^2.
$$
So a square equals a negative number.  Hence there is no solution.  The two circles do not intersect.

Comment: this is not correct - the distance between the centres of the circles works out to be exactly 2.5 - so 2 intersection points do exist

Comment: @WWI : Your comment is not correct.  The $y$-coordinates of the centers in the question as stated initially were $3$ and $2.5$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I realized later than they were wrong, sry about that I am still happy that you answered! Micheal Hardy!
Do you have a Idea what how to calculate the intersection point, that was, what this question was about, you seem like you could know?
Thank you!

Comment: @hopefulguest could you confirm what the 2 centre points should be - they have changed since last time I looked - now circle 2 only seems to have one coordinate !

Comment: Two circles are given in the Cartesian plane, with centers (x0,y0)(x0,y0) and (x1,y1)(x1,y1) and respective radii r1r1 and r2r2. I'm trying to find a formula for the points where these two circles intersect.

Comment: Circle 1 is x0=1 y0=1 and r0=1 ///
Circle 2 is x1=3 y1=2.5 or  with r1=2
I hope you understand it now.

Comment: @hopefulGuest are the centres at (1,1) and (3,2.5)  or perhaps (1,3) and (1,2.5) as Michael's answer suggests

Comment: Yeah one circle centers in (1,1) and the other circle centers in (3,2.5)
the radius of the first circle is 1 and the radius of the second circle is 2

Comment: @MichaelHardy my apologies for being so blunt, it hadn't ocurred to me that the question might have changed